# Reshaping a data.frame so a column containing multiple features becomes multiple binary columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this

```
df <-data.frame(id = c(1,2),
                value = c(25,24),
                features = c("A,B,D,F","C,B,E"))

print(df)

id,value,features
1,25,"A,B,D,F"
2,24,"C,B,E"
```

I want to reshape it into this:

```
id,value,A,B,C,D,E,F
1,25,1,1,0,1,0,1
2,24,0,1,1,0,1,0
```

I'm guessing that the first step would be to identify the unique values in the `df$features` column, but once I have that list, I'm not sure what an efficient (i.e. vectorized) way to create the final dataset would be.

This feels like an operation for `dplyr` or `reshape2` but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: is `df$features` always of the same lenght?

Comment: no,the length of  `df$features` varies. - I'll edit the example to clarify this.

Answer (score 3):

This is yet another use case for `merge` after suitable transformation.

```
library(reshape2)
f<-with(df,stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(features),","),id)))
d<-dcast(f,ind~values,length,value.var="ind")
out<-merge(df[,1:2],d,by.x="id",by.y="ind")

print(out)
```

```
  id value A B C D E F
1  1    25 1 1 0 1 0 1
2  2    24 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

This can also be done using only default libraries (without `reshape2`) in a variety of slightly messier ways. In the above, you can substitute the `d` and `out` lines with the following instead:

```
d<-xtabs(count~ind+values,transform(f,count=1))
out<-merge(df[,1:2],as.data.frame.matrix(d),by.x="id",by.y="row.names")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(qdapTools)

df1 = data.frame(cSplit(df, 'features', sep=',', type.convert=F))
cbind(df1[1:2], mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df1[-c(1,2)]))))

#   id value A B C D E F
#1:  1    25 1 1 0 1 0 1
#2:  2    24 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: There's also `cSplit_e`: `cSplit_e(df, "features", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)`.

Comment: your package is insane.

Answer (score 2):

Another one using `splitstackshape` and `data.table` (installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)):

```
require(splitstackshape)
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
ans <- cSplit(df, 'features', sep = ',', 'long')
dcast(ans, id + value ~ features, fun.aggregate = length)
#    id value A B C D E F
# 1:  1    25 1 1 0 1 0 1
# 2:  2    24 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

If you're using `data.table v1.9.4`, then replace `dcast` with `dcast.data.table`.

Alternatively, you can use `cSplit_e`, like this:

```
cSplit_e(df, "features", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
##   id value features features_A features_B features_C features_D features_E features_F
## 1  1    25  A,B,D,F          1          1          0          1          0          1
## 2  2    24    C,B,E          0          1          1          0          1          0
```

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr/tidyr solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

separate(df,features,1:4,",",extra="merge") %>%
  gather(key,letter,-id,-value) %>%
  filter(!is.na(letter)) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  mutate(n=1) %>%
  spread(letter,n) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.),0,1)),A:F)
```